# Error while running outlier function in R

Tags: r

Hi im getting error while passing a data train with vector "Attr1","Attr2"

Train is data name
Attr1,Attr2 are column names
i need to replace all outlier values with NA

```
outlierKD <- function(dt, var) {
  print(var)
  for (i in var) {
    print(i)
    var_name <- eval(as.character(substitute(i)),eval(dt))
    outlier<-boxplot.stats(var_name)$out
    var_name<-ifelse(var_name %in% outlier,NA,var_name)
    dt[as.character(substitute(i))] <- invisible(var_name)
    assign(as.character(as.list(match.call())$dt), dt, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    message("Outliers successfully removed", "\n")
  }
  return(invisible(dt))
}
```

> ####################Errorpart############################################## outlierKD   (train, c("Attr2","Attr3")) [1] "Attr2" "Attr3" [1] "Attr2"
>
> Show Traceback    Rerun with Debug  Error in x[floor(d)] +
>   x[ceiling(d)] :    non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Please provide [example data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) in order to make your issue reproducible!